# What is the Aggregate in the context of DDD

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I am reading some literature regarding using design pattern and trying to see how they fit into my business model. I need to reminded what does an Aggregate of an object X mean in terms of Domain Driven Design. Would it be the same as the aggregate root?

Answer (score 1):

Collaboration of entity and value object and group of associated object in a system to represent a context is aggregate. Each aggregate has one root(aggregate root) which is entity and it is the only accessible object in the aggregate from outside.
to talking to entity, value object of a aggregate you should talk to aggregate root and also you should create repository for aggregate root only.
I've written a short article about DDD concepts [here](http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/15/domain-driven-design-alphabet), take a look for more info.